# Seperate listbox items to do a for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, listbox

I'm having trouble seperating my listbox items, so I can run them in a loop. I know this atm takes all items and tries to run them through, however I don't know how to seperate them.
The code is following:

```
Dim SelectedItems As String
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
SelectedItems = SelectedItems & ListBox2.List(i) & vbNewLine
End If
Next i

If SelectedItems = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select minimum one country"
Else

For Each SelectedItems In ListBox2

    For i = 11 To LastRow

    If Range("F" & i).Value = SelectedItems Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else: Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    Next i
Next SelectedItems
```

can someone assist?

Comment: What do you mean with "seperate them"? Do you want to loop a range and do something when that value is selected in a listbox? Are multiple items selected?

Comment: The listbox presents a list of countries. The user should be able to choose 1 or more countries and then the macro should filter a table on the users choice no matter if 1 country or several countries are selected. What I want to do is that the macro runs each choice through a table afterwards in order to filter. Hope that clarifies?

Comment: So the choises of the listbox determines the filter? Pick (multiple)  countries in the listbox and the rows should be visible when the country is picked? If not picked, it should be invisible?

Comment: Yes exactly right

Comment: One more question. Where is your listbox situated? On a userform or on your worksheet?

Comment: It's in a userform but both solutions would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim SelectedItems As String, LastRow As Long
Dim selItem As Variant, selItems As Variant

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
        SelectedItems = SelectedItems & ListBox2.List(i) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next i

Stop
If SelectedItems = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please select minimum one country"
Else
    SelectedItems = left(SelectedItems, Len(SelectedItems) - 1)
    selItems = Split(SelectedItems, vbNewLine)
    For Each selItem In selItems
        For i = LastRow To 11 Step -1
            If CStr(Range("F" & i).value) = CStr(selItem) Then
                Stop
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                'Else: Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End If
```

Your code could not identify each selected Item from the string without splitting it in its elements.
Edited: Transformed the code in a test one. I will explain you (in a comment) how to check.

Note: I just tried to make your code workable. Otherwise, you can make the filtering directly, using Excel AutoFilter (in VBA,  of course)...

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't filter the list properly. Any idea why?

Comment: @Gisse: I adapted a little the code in order to offer you a check possibility. Run it and it will stop before the line `If SelectedItems = "" Then`. Move the mouse over the line in discussion and you can see the value of `SelectedItems`. If there are records in this variable, this means that the code works well until that point. In such a case press F5. If `Range("F" & i).value` will be equal with `selItem` another `Stop` will confirm that and now it's time to run the code line by line and see what it does.

Comment: @Gisse: So check what value `i` takes, press F8 and see in the workbook if the row `i` has been hide. If not try to understand where the problem is, or post here a brief description of what happened.

Comment: @Gisse: Until now I couldn't test the code I posted. I just observed what is wrong regarding the individual selected item identification. Now I checked the code itself. Like you can see, I commented the part `Else: Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False`. If this part remains, your code firstly will hide the selected item row but after that, during the iteration will make it visible and you cannot see nothing else then your initial column composition.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that it doesn't hide anything either. However why is this the case with above code. I guess I can just delete it making it do what it is supposed to. However why is this?
It worked when I ran this code as a test on another sheet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. My code doesn't hide anything even with deletion of the code you suggested. The ```range("F" & i).value = Selitem``` is exactly the same value, but somehow it doesn't recognize it. At least it doesn't hide the row. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Gisse: But you did what I suggested? In order to understand something you must come back with some (real) feedback. Saying that it does not work/hide does not say too much to me. So, does `SelectedItems` looks as expected? Did you understand how to check that? If yes, this means that the code collected all selected issues in a string works. Secondly, when the code stops at the second `Stop` line, did you press F8 fore some times and **look to the Excel page to check if the row `i` is hidden** (or not), after each F8 press?

Comment: @Gisse:  If not, how do you believe that we can determine the problem of the code? In my case it works! If you do not understand what I suggested, can you post a link to your real workbook to be able to test the code by myself?

Comment: @Gisse: Did the code stop to the second `Stop` line?

Comment: Yes I've run the entire code through by clicking F8. However I don't know what the stop command does?
In my case it doesn't hide the row and I don't understand why. I check a long the way and the value of the SelItem is exactly the same as the range in the loop. Let me get back to you. Thanks for your help though

Comment: No it doesn't stop on the second stop line. What does this mean?

Comment: @Gisse: The `Stop` "command" does exactly what it means: It stops the code on its line... Does your code stop on `Stop` line? At least, on the first Stop? If yes, I told you to move the mouse over the variable to be checked and its value will appear. Is it as expected? If the second `Stop` line is not touched this means that the condition before it is not true. Maybe you run the code on a different sheet, or whatever.

Comment: @Gisse: In order to be sure that the data in the cell is the same with the one collected form list box you can change the code as following: `If CStr(Range("F" & i).value) = CStr(selItem) Then`. It transforms everything in string.   I asked you to send a link to your workbook. Cleaned by confidential data if this is the case. Otherwise, it looks we speak two different languages. Sorry...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide link.

Comment: OK. No problem with me. If you are able to describe what I requested in order to be able to help, I will try my best. If not, I wish you all the best, anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

So just a small example on how I would approach this, avoiding multiple loops:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>UserForm Sample:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>UserForm Sample Code:</sub>***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim x As Long, lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

'Check if anything has been selected at all
If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Capture selected items in your ListBox
For x = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(x) Then
        dict(ListBox1.List(x)) = 1
    End If
Next x

'Filter the range accordingly
With Sheet1
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    rng.AutoFilter 1, Array(dict.keys), xlFilterValues
End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lr As Long

'Populate your ListBox
With Sheet1
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = .Range("A2:A" & lr).Address
End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Sample Result:</sub>***

[image]
[image]